# url rewriting for asp.net under mono xsp2

Tags: asp.net, mono, url-rewriting, xsp

I'm trying to do some asp.net development on a Mac right now and i'm having trouble finding a urlrewriting library that works fine under mono (and the xsp2 webserver)

Of course you could write your own, but i have a bunch of rules already created and i dont want to rewrite(!) them in code if dont have to.

i've used [UrlRewriter.Net](http://urlrewriter.net/) in this project before but that doesn't seem to work, now i tried [ManagedFusion URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com/), but that one fails on XSP2 too.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, URL Rewriter's site says it works on Mono.

Is this the same capabilities provided by System.Web.Routing?  Mono ships with that now.